# how do i install fineuploader in osclass script?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader, osclass

I faced some problems with my fineuploader v3.8 in osclass.

The picture upload button is not working. Before this, when I try to upload a simple image, it shows this error message

> "Upload failure reason unknown"

Here my item post section:

```
<?php } ?>
<?php if( osc_images_enabled_at_items() ) {
?>
<li class="defHide">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<span class="title-plan">
Choose image 
</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<?php ItemForm::ajax_photos(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

so what is the problem? I don't know, please tell me how to change and upgrade this uploader script. I really need help for this, so any help is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly an issue with your server. You'll need to take a look at the http requests for more information.

Comment: I sent a ticket to hosting support and they told there is no problem on server side.i tried a simple uploader and it worked fine.surely there is another problem is here. i checked permissions also. but no result ...

Comment: You'll need to take a look at the http requests for more information. Or the JavaScript console. There is nothing that can be done with the little information you have provided.

Comment: thanks for your answer mate. how can i find http requests?